# NoClassDefFoundError javax/servlet/Registration$Dynamic with spring boot + spring boot legacy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am deploying spring boot 1.4.2 to weblogic 10.3 ... I am including `spring-boot-legacy` to handle the servlet version compatibility issue (3.0 / 2.5) ... I am getting this error when deploying :

```
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Registration$Dynamic
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration.messageDispatcherServlet(WebServicesAutoConfiguration.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$77b29a1f.CGLIB$messageDispatcherServlet$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$77b29a1f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f1781529.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$77b29a1f.messageDispatcherServlet(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

What is weird here is that `javax/servlet/Registration$Dynamic` is accessed in **spring boot 2.0.0 by `ServletRegistrationBean`**... The corresponding in **spring boot 1.4.2 is `ServletRegistration.Dynamic`**   which should be handled in `spring-boot-legacy`

```
@ConditionalOnMissingClass("javax.servlet.ServletRegistration")
@AutoConfigureAfter({
        MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MetricFilterAutoConfiguration {
```

EDIT : 
build.gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-legacy:1.1.0.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.2.RELEASE')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.7') //java6
    compile('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.2.4.RELEASE')
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.2'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
    }
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10')
    compileOnly('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.1.0.7.0') //java6
    //compileOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compileOnly('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5')
    //compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))

    //jaxb "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.7"
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat') // commented for java6
    providedRuntime('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.59') // java6
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-jdbc', version: '7.0.59'
```

EDIT : gradle dependency tree:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-legacy:1.1.0.RELEASE
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.4.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.20 -> 1.7.21
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.21
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.21
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.21
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.4.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.2.1.Final -> 3.3.0.Final
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.1.0 -> 1.3.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.4 -> 2.6.7
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0 -> 2.8.4
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.7 -> 2.8.4
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.4.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.7 (*)
+--- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core -> 2.3.1.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:2.3.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-oxm:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.2.0
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.3.RELEASE -> 1.4.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.4.3.RELEASE -> 1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.6
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:8.5.6 -> 7.0.59
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    |              +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.0
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.4.3.RELEASE -> 1.4.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.mybatis:mybatis:3.4.2
|    \--- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.3.1
+--- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10
+--- com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.1.0.7.0
\--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.59
```

Comment: No it shouldn't be handled. That is not what `spring-boot-legacy` is doing nor proving. It only allows you to start an older Spring Boot application (as in not requiring a Servlet 3.0 API) on a 2.5 container by providing ServletListener implementations to mimic the Spring Boot behavior. Apparently you have included a dependency which requires a servlet 3.1 container and there is nothing in `spring-boot-legacy` that will help you overcome that.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum ... actually I checked all my dependencies to make sure that none uses 3.1 ... even I searched the entire application for `Registration.Dynamic` ... I found that only `ServletRegistration.Dynamic` is the one used in the dependency libraries ... also I corrected the question with the bold parts

Comment: Your versions are a mess (or your question ont sure) but what is you are using 1.2.4, 1.4.2 or is it 2.0.0... You are mentioning a lot of versions ... And as stated nothing will be handled in `spring-boot-legacy` as that only contains bootstrapping code for your Spring Boot application.

Comment: sorry it's 1.4.2 .. I edited it

Comment: and as you said : "It only allows you to start an older Spring Boot application (as in not requiring a Servlet 3.0 API) on a 2.5 container by providing ServletListener implementations to mimic the Spring Boot behavior" ... this is exactly my case ... I am running an old spring boot app (1.4.2) on 2.5 container (weblogic 10) ... the issue is that it tells that it's not able to find some class (which is in boot 2.0.0 indeed) though I am pretty sure that this class shouldn't be accessed from my application as none of my dependencies use boot 2.0.0 stuff

Comment: You are using the Spring Boot Mybatis stuff which requires boot 1.5 or up (you need to use the 1.2.x versions). I would also suggest using the `spring-boot-starter-webservices` instead of including plain `spring-ws`.

Comment: mmm ... thank you I will check it , though I am not sure why it might cause a problem ... I will also post the dependency tree generated by gradle